# How to disable classList on only hover and not styling

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
nxt_question_btn.classList.remove('btns')
```

```css
.btns{
    margin-top: 10px;
    float: right;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: lightblue;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 110px;
}
.btns:hover{
    border: 1px solid black;
    box-shadow: 2px 1px 5px lightblue;
}
```

```html
        <button id="next" class="btns">Next Question</button>
        <button id="end" class="btns">End Quiz</button>
```

I want to disable the hover option when the button is disabled, my Javascript currently disbles the styling and the hover option. How can I target the hover only?

Comment: In general, you could consider using an additional class, e.g. using the selectors `.btns` and `.btns-hover:hover`. Then you can control the two classes `btns` and `btns-hover` separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`:not()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) pseudo class to only apply the hover style when the button does not have the `disabled` attribute.

```css
.btns{
    margin-top: 10px;
    float: right;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: lightblue;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 110px;
}
.btns:not([disabled]):hover{
    border: 1px solid black;
    box-shadow: 2px 1px 5px lightblue;
}
```

```html
<button id="next" class="btns">Next Question</button>
        <button id="end" class="btns" disabled>End Quiz</button>
```

Alternatively, [you can also use the CSS `disabled` pseudo class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71367233/how-to-disable-classlist-on-only-hover-and-not-styling/71367235?noredirect=1#comment126146257_71367235) as the selector.

Comment: CSS has its own pseudoclass for disabled, so you can just do `.btns:not(:disabled):hover`. I would also re-order it to `.btns:hover:not(:disabled)`.

Answer (score 0):

I also want to mention that if you already have a style for `:disabled`, you can add the hover state to it:

```css
.btns {
  margin-top: 10px;
  float: right;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 110px;
}

.btns:hover {
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-shadow: 2px 1px 5px lightblue;
}

.btns:disabled, .btns:disabled:hover {
  border: lightgray;
  box-shadow: none;
  cursor: no-drop;
}
```

```html
<button id="next" class="btns">Next Question</button>
<button id="end" class="btns" disabled>End Quiz</button>
```